# how to develop the environment for php in Linux OS

Tags: php, linux, lamp

as the title description .

first studying the programme of php ,want to make the codes in Linux .

therefore ,develop LAMP is neccessary and I want to understand hwo to construct environment.

Comment: `yum install php-mysql mysql-server`

Comment: Well, if you're on a Red Hat derivative Linux... That command won't do anything on my Arch box.

Comment: Every Major linux distro has a package management system, you can use that to install php, required packages are PHP, apache, mysql

Answer (score 1):

Since you say you are using Ubuntu and CentOS.

[LAMP Tutorial from HowtoForge for Ubuntu 12.04](http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-apache2-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-ubuntu-12.04-lts-lamp)

[LAMP Tutorial from HowtoForge for CentOS](http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-apache2-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-centos-6.2-lamp)

And for anyone else looking to make a LAMP, with minor modifications this should work in any distro.

Comment: It seems to be the best understood by the newer LAMP users :)

Comment: the version of linux which I am using now is two : Ubuntu 12.04 and CentOs. Linux for me  , is beginning!

Answer (score 0):

What type of Linux? If you are using Debian or Ubuntu this is one of the best beginner friendly guides:

http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_lamp_for_newbies

It shows how to install Apache/PHP/MySQL/ and PHPMyAdmin

You might run into some errors when trying to install the latter but one of the comments under the article has the right solution for that.

Comment: Thanks for you first , and then try it on my machine!